# How to adapt C++ Makefile to allow for using openmpi parallelization compiling several files into 1 executable

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, cygwin, openmpi

Just a disclaimer I'm not too experienced with Make files, so forgive me if the answer is simple! I have a Make file that compiles several .cpp & .h files into .o files, and then produces an executable.

I am using g++ as the compiler currently. I'd like to adapt this file to allow for openmpi multi-core computing. To note: I'm on a Windows 11 x 64 architecture, using Cygwin to build run this cpp code. I also would like this to run on MacOS systems as well.

In particular, the parallelization macros are only in 1 .cpp file, what I'd consider the 'main' file of this project (mag_spec_tracker.cpp). I don't know if that makes a difference here but thought it could be useful to let be known.

My current Makefile is below - note I added a line to try and grab the mpicc compile flags, but I am unsure on how to use them here.

```
IDIR = include
CXX = g++ 
CXXFLAGS = -I$(IDIR) -std=c++17
ODIR = obj
_DEPS = my_functions.h particle.h beam.h threevector.h threematrix.h screen.h magnet.h
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))
_OBJ = my_functions.o particle.o beam.o mag_spec_tracker.o screen.o magnet.o 
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

$(ODIR)/%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CXXFLAGS)

run: $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(CXXFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(IDIR)/*~
```

I have tried adding lines into the Makefile to get the mpi compile flags based on other reference I've found online, but was unsure how to adapt my current code to add these flags to allow for correct usage of openmpi. The lines I added to grab compile flags were:

```
MPI_COMPILE_FLAGS = $(shell mpicc --showme:compile)
MPI_LINK_FLAGS = $(shell mpicc --showme:link)
```

Thank you in advance!

**Update (12/6/2022)**

Responding to the comment from Matzeri ('for opempi the compiler is mpicc not gcc. for c++ is mpicxx not g++'), I replaced 'g++' in my makefile with 'mpicxx' and recieved the following error:

```
    $ make
mpicxx -c -o obj/mag_spec_tracker.o mag_spec_tracker.cpp -Iinclude -std=c++17
mpicxx -o run obj/my_functions.o obj/particle.o obj/beam.o obj/mag_spec_tracker.o obj/screen.o obj/magnet.o -Iinclude -std=c++17
C:/Users/Jason/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmpi_cxx: No such file or directory
C:/Users/Jason/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmpi: No such file or directory
C:/Users/Jason/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lopen-rte: No such file or directory
C:/Users/Jason/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lopen-pal: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:19: run] Error 1
```

I notice that its looking for an ld executable in 'mingw64'. I tried removing that directory (previously I had installed mingw64, but switched to cygwin), and got the following error:

```
$ make
mpicxx -o run obj/my_functions.o obj/particle.o obj/beam.o obj/mag_spec_tracker.o obj/screen.o obj/magnet.o -Iinclude -std=c++17
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
The Open MPI wrapper compiler was unable to find the specified compiler
g++ in your PATH.

Note that this compiler was either specified at configure time or in
one of several possible environment variables.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
make: *** [Makefile:19: run] Error 1
```

I also added `c:\cygwin\bin` to my environment paths, and this issue still occurs. I confirmed that mpicxx is in that bin folder.

Any ideas?

Comment: for opempi the compiler is mpicc not gcc. for c++ is mpicxx not g++

Comment: Thank you, I replaced gcc with mpicxx and recieved the following error in the 'update' in the post

Comment: @matzeri , is the answer as simple as switching compliers to mpicxx for the entire project? If so I'll accept your answer as the answer to this question, with the understanding that I'm having a secondary issue at this point which isn't related to the original question.

Comment: Hello there, I've gotten it to compile now - however, parallelization is not working correctly. I'm only getting 1 thread in my parallel sections of my code. Will post an update, in case its related to this issue. If its unrelated I'll open a new question

Comment: How are you running the code ?